# Rails - How to Fix secrets.yml.enc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not great with Linux environments. Building an app in Ruby on Rails with Cloud9 via AWS. It's Rails 5.1 so using secrets but trying my hand at encrypted secrets.

I went and started the process with the rails secrets:setup no problem

I then started editing the file with the edit:secrets so that it would encrypt properly.

Unfortunately I used a "tab" in the file instead of just spaces. Now when I go back to edit the file, it gives me an error about finding an unaproved yaml character and won't let me edit the file.

I've tried re-runing secrets:setup to try to restart the process but to no avail. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just delete the 2 secret files and start again? 'config/secrets.yml.key' and 'config/secrets.yml.enc' ?

Comment: @Adam21e that worked! would you like to submit as answer? I wasn't sure if I could delete them after creation, i expected that just running the secrets:setup file would have overwritten them (which it didn't), but deleting then running again did work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delete the 2 secret files and start again:

```
config/secrets.yml.key
config/secrets.yml.enc
```